# C++: Pointer to class member function inside a non-related structure

Tags: c++, function-pointers, member-functions

I've done a bit of reading online as to how to go about this and I think I'm doing it correctly... My goal is to have an array of structure objects that contain pointers to member-functions of a class.

Here's what I have so far...

```
typedef void (foo::*HandlerPtr)(...);
class foo
{
public:
    void someFunc(...);
    // ...
private:
    // ...
};

struct STRUCT
{
    HandlerPtr handler;
};

STRUCT stuff[]
{
    {&foo::someFunc}
};
```

Then when calling the function using (stuff[0].*handler)(), with or without arguments (I do actually intend to use argument lists), I get "handler": Undeclared identifier...

I've got to be missing something, just don't know what.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

someFunc() is not a static method, so you need a foo object instance in order to call someFunc() via your pointer-to-method variable, ie:

```
foo f;
f.*(stuff[0].handler)();
```

Or:

```
foo f;
HandlerPtr mthd = stuff[0].handler;
f.*mthd();
```

Or, using pointers:

```
foo *f = new foo;
f->*(stuff[0].handler)();
delete f;
```

Or:

```
foo *f = new foo;
HandlerPtr mthd = stuff[0].handler;
f->*mthd();
delete f;
```